# Declaring variable in if statement (good practice in ES2016)

Tags: ecmascript-6

In ES2016, I'm wondering if this is best practice to declare a variable in an if statement:

***ECMA2016***

```
let x = 1
if (false) {
  x = 0
}
console.log(x) // 1
```

***before ES2016, using var***

```
if (true) {
  var x = 1
} else {
  var x = 0
}
console.log(x) // 1
```

Comment: I think you meant ES2015 also, the same can be applied with `var` as well.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice in ES5 would really be

```
var x;
if (true) {
  x = 1
} else {
  x = 0
}
```

Or even

```
var x = true ? 1 : 0;
```

Because it's always clearest to define a var at the top of the functional scope (even if you're not ready to assign anything to it yet) and also to only define it once.

With ES2015 your example is right: you should define x in the highest scope/block level you intend it to be used in.

Answer (score -1):

Using ECMA2016 you can't declare new variable in if block and then use otside that block. So, your variant looks good.

Comment: Uh? `if (true) { var x = 1; }; console.log(x);` works just fine.

Comment: I think IIiya meant that you can't do that with let.  var would still work fine in that case, though it's probably still a best practice to define var x; at the top of the scope it's meant to be used, even if you aren't ready to assign anything to it.

Comment: A `var` is scoped to the function. There is no notion of declaring it in the block. Using ES6, people should avoid var declarations and declare variables using `let` or `const` that have semantics similar to many block-structured languages (Java, in particular). There is no ECMAScript2016 specification, there is ECMAScript2015 (ES6), which has been adopted, and ECMAScript2017, which is under review.